# End multi scripts running on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, exit

I am trying to end the process of multi-scripts running on tkinter by a click of the end process created button. However, this does not seem to work when any of the scripts are running in an infinite loop to stop the process.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmsg

root = Tk(className=" x") # creates root window

# all components of thw window will come here
Label(root,text='Enter Load Value or Choose a test action',font=("Helvetica", 16), width=40, height=2).pack(side=TOP)
svalue = StringVar() # defines the widget state as string
w = Entry(root,textvariable=svalue).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10) # adds a textarea widget

def act():
    print ("Value entered")
    print ('%s' % svalue.get())

def script_1():
    os.system('python script1_1.py')

def script_2():
    os.system('python script1_2.py')
    global root
    while 1:
        root.update()
        pass

def script_3():
    os.system('python script1_3.py')

def script_4():
    os.system('python script1_4.py')

def script_5():
    os.system('python script1_5.py')

def quit():
    tkmsg.showinfo("Stopped", "Stopped")
    sys.exit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global root
    root = Frame ()
    root.pack ()

button0 = Button(root,text="Load", command=act).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
button1 = Button(root,text="Test 1",command=script_1).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
button2 = Button(root,text="Test 2",command=script_2).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
button3 = Button(root,text="Test 3",command=script_3).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
button4 = Button(root,text="Test 4",command=script_4).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
button5 = Button(root,text="Test 5",command=script_5).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
button6 = Button(root,fg="red",text="End      process",command=quit).pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)

button.mainloop() # an event loop to invoke custom function "act"
root.mainloop() # To keep GUI window running
```

Comment: You have two infinite loops in code - `while 1:`  and `root.mainloop()` . You can have only `root.mainloop()`.  Use `root.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to run function periodically and mimic `while True:` loop.

Comment: instead of `var = Widget().pack()` you should use `var = Widget()` and `var.pack()` or if you don't need `var` then `Widget().pack()`

Comment: use `p = subprocess.Popen()` (instead of `os.system()`) which doesn't stop main process and has `p.kill()` function.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!